# Logical error in validation of numbers along with Percentage symbol in React Js

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my project I have a field named **Rate** which can accept these values:
Eg:

- 2.32
- 2.32%

Conditions:

- Only numbers are allowed.
- Only two digits after decimal point.
- No letters and other symbols permitted.

This is the piece of code I'm using

```
handleCheck = (e)=> {
    let onlyNums = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9\.,%]/g, ''); 
    var str = '';
    var isperc = false;    
    if(onlyNums.indexOf('.') !== -1)
    {     
      var arr = onlyNums.split(".");
      if(arr[1].length >2)
      {
        if( arr[1].indexOf('%') !== -1)
          isperc = true;
        arr[1] = arr[1].slice(0, 2);
      }
      if(isperc)
        e.target.value = arr[0] + '.' + arr[1] + '%';
      else
        e.target.value = arr[0] + '.' + arr[1];
    }
    if(onlyNums.indexOf('%') !== -1)
    {
      str = onlyNums.indexOf('%');
      var start = (str + 1);     
      onlyNums = e.target.value.slice(0, start);
      e.target.value=onlyNums;
    }

  }
```

[image]

The above picture shows the problem. The **Rate** field is accepting letters also before putting a decimal point.

how should I modify my code to avoid this problem? Or 
How can I convert `\d+(\.\d\d)?%?` regex similar to the one I used inside the **replace** function in the question, because this regex is not working with my code

Comment: Couldn't you just use a regex for all your test? Like `\d+(\.\d\d)?%?` for example? (https://regex101.com/r/vTkgMH/2)

Comment: @Bhojendra Rauniyar I have changed my code like this
`let onlyNums = e.target.value.replace(/\d+(\.\d\d)?%?/g, ''); 
    e.target.value = onlyNums`
It's not working as expected.
Is the problem associated with the way I used the regex inside replace function
If so what's the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed a bit the *regex*, and added a `parseFloat()` on top. Also called to change the input's value just after the first replace call. That may be something that you missed in the first place.

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
  
  handleCheck = (e)=> {
    let onlyNums = e.target.value.replace(/[^.%\d]?(\.\%)/g, ''); 
    e.target.value = isNaN(parseFloat(onlyNums))?'':parseFloat(onlyNums);

    var str = '';
    var isperc = false;    
    if(onlyNums.indexOf('.') !== -1)
    {     
      var arr = onlyNums.split(".");
      if(arr[1].length >2)
      {
        if( arr[1].indexOf('%') !== -1)
          isperc = true;
        arr[1] = arr[1].slice(0, 2);
      }
      if(isperc)
        e.target.value = arr[0] + '.' + arr[1] + '%';
      else
        e.target.value = arr[0] + '.' + arr[1];
    }
    if(onlyNums.indexOf('%') !== -1)
    {
      str = onlyNums.indexOf('%');
      var start = (str + 1);     
      onlyNums = e.target.value.slice(0, start);
      e.target.value=onlyNums;
    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input onChange={this.handleCheck} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Input />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">

</div>
```

**EDIT (a more *regex* approach):**

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.input_prev_value = ''; //property for storing previous input value
    }

    handleCheck = (e)=> {
        let input_value = e.target.value.replace(/(\.\%)/,'');  //takes care of '.%' case

        if((input_value.search(/^[0]{1,}[\d]/)!==-1 || // takes care of leading zeroes
            input_value.search(/^(\d+)([\.])?([\d]{1,2})?([\%])?$/)===-1) &&  //main pattern
            input_value!=='')
            e.target.value  = this.input_prev_value;
        else {
            e.target.value = input_value;
            this.input_prev_value = e.target.value;
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input onChange={this.handleCheck} />
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Input />,
        document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```